# Centering text in emacs window

Tags: emacs, latex

Inside just one lonely emacs frame I switch frequently between editting 70-column text files (LaTeX) and 120-column programs (.h/.cpp files). I'd like to continue to use just one emacs frame, without resizing it or creating additional frames.

Here is the problem. The width of my window is about right for editting the 120-column programs, but during the extended text editting sessions, the 70 columns appear on the left side of the window. At the end of the day in front of a laptop, my neck seems to have acquired a semi-permanent tilt to the left.

Are you aware of a method to make the text appear centered, while still making the text files remain jagged on the right?

Comment: Switch to Hebrew? (right to left)  :P   It sounds as though you generally edit in a single *window* - would you be open to a solution which arranges windows for you automatically - a single one for editing code, two side-by-side for text (with the one on the left being empty/unused)?

Comment: Switching between two windows is indeed quite easy. On a Mac the keystrokes to switch are even briefer than the C-x o or C-x b business in emacs. But the esthetics are bad. Because I need just about emacs and nothing else, my display is very tidy: there is just this one window. Having two windows mean that text from the lower larger one will be visible and clutter my view.

Comment: You can arrange the windows side-by-side, having an empty one on the left taking up 50 columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try narrowing the frame by increasing the fringe size.  For example:

```
(set-fringe-style '(200 . 200))
```

would shave 200 pixels off each side of the main text area, leaving the work area 400 pixels narrower but still centered.  To return to the regular view,

```
(set-fringe-style 'default)
```

will revert the fringe to the normal size.

And you can wrap that up inside some advice, which might work well for you if you stick to using just a single window:

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (after switch-to-buffer-adjust-fringe activate)
  "depending on major mode, switch fringe style"
  (if (memq major-mode '(latex-mode))
  (set-fringe-style '(200 . 200))
(set-fringe-style 'default)))
```

*Note:* Update the list `(latex-mode)` to contain whatever modes you want to have the large fringes.

Comment: Fantastic, but it's only useful if it's automated. How do I trigger this to happen when I am editting a .tex file, but not when I am editting .txt file, a Makefile, or even a dired buffer?

Comment: @Calaf I updated the answer to automate the solution, which can be customized to fit your exact Emacs usage.

Answer (score 0):

EmacsWiki has a page on [shrink-wrapping frames](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Shrink-Wrapping_Frames). You could use the libraries and code referenced there to automatically shrink and grow your Emacs frame as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
;; Add left and right margins, when file is markdown or text.
(defun center-window (window) ""
  (let* ((current-extension (file-name-extension (or (buffer-file-name) "foo.unknown")))
         (max-text-width 80)
         (margin (max 0 (/ (- (window-width window) max-text-width) 2))))
    (if (and (not (string= current-extension "md"))
             (not (string= current-extension "txt")))
        ;; Do nothing if this isn't an .md or .txt file.
        ()
      (set-window-margins window margin margin))))

;; Adjust margins of all windows.
(defun center-windows () ""
  (walk-windows (lambda (window) (center-window window)) nil 1))

;; Listen to window changes.
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'center-windows)
```

Add your file extensions above, below "md" and "txt".

Comment: A user is trying to get help making this snippet work in http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/4112/115 Can you please help out? The person can't comment here as (s)he doesn't have enough rep to comment on answers.