# Centering text in Emacs buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to define a function which will keep my fixed width body in Emacs centered in the buffer rather than aligned to the left side. In particular I want this to be buffer-local, and I'm trying to do this by locally setting left- and right-margin-width.

This works fine by itself, but I also want a hook to adjust the margins when the window size changes, and this is causing problems for me. Here's the code (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23731757/3822233):

```
(defun center-body ()
  (let* ((max-text-width 70)
         (margin (max 0 (/ (- (window-width) max-text-width) 2))))
    (setq-local left-margin-width margin)
    (setq-local right-margin-width margin)
    (set-window-buffer nil (current-buffer))))

(defun uncenter-body ()
  (setq-local left-margin-width 0)
  (setq-local right-margin-width 0)
  (set-window-buffer nil (current-buffer)))

(defun body-center-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (if (= left-margin-width 0)
      (progn
        (center-body))
        (add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'center-body nil 1))                                                        
    (uncenter-body)
    (remove-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'center-body 1)))
```

When the `add-hook` and `remove-hook` lines are removed, everthing's ok. But as soon as I call the `add-hook` I get a **nesting exceeds max-lisp-eval-depth** error.

I don't really understand lisp so I'm having trouble debugging this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `set-window-buffer` will end up running `window-configuration-change-hook`.
So I'd recommend you only call `set-window-buffer` when `left-margin-width` or `right-margin-width` actually changes.

But in any case you'll get into trouble as soon as your buffer gets displayed in 2 or more windows of different width.
So the better answer is to not use `left-margin-width` and `right-margin-width` but instead to use `set-window-margins`.
Not only this will not call `window-configuration-change-hook` and hence won't suffer from this infinite recursion problem, but on top of that, it will happily adjust the margins differently for every window that displays the buffer, depending on those windows's widths.

Comment: thanks! went with `set-window-margins` and things are working just fine.